# Aruba 2530 - IGMP Enabled, Querier on still no filtering

Tags: vlan, hp, igmp, aruba

I have a in port 1 - 5 channels of multicast. On port 2 i have a computer. Both are in VLAN 10 untagged and a more bigger network tagged on port 3.

I've enabled IGMP with: config, vlan 10, ip igmp, ip igmp querier

Everything seems to start, only thing is that when it get querier job it still pushes all 5 channels to my PC on TCPdump.

Any idea why the igmp is not working properly?

Comment: Did you enable IGMP snooping on the switch to let the layer-2 snoop on the IGMP messages?

Comment: There you just went a bit over my head, trying to google but if you'd like to elaborate on that?

Comment: IGMP is used to communicate between the hosts wanting multicast and a multicast router. Normally, layer-2 switches would not look at the IGMP messages, but IGMP snooping was created to allow switches to inspect the IGMP messages so that they can determine which switch inter aces should get the multicast frames, and which have not requested frames for a multicast group. There are also some multicast groups that are sent to every interface, regardless.

Comment: Multicast groups are 239.0.0.1 to 5, what command is it to enable IGMP snooping on this switch? I've been looking for that functionality a lot on the internet before asking here, and all i find is "use ip igmp" to enable.

Comment: I don't know for that switch model, and not all switches have IGMP snooping. The default is that multicast, like broadcast, is sent to every switch interface. IGMP snooping was designed to let a switch make more intelligent decisions about where to send multicast frames by listening to the host-to-multicast-router IGMP conversations.

Comment: According to the manual, you create a snooping profile and enable it for a VLAN profile. I don't know which code version you are running, but for 7.4.x, it starts on page 249 of the manual.

Comment: The "ip igmp" command on an Aruba switch actually enables both IGMP (if it is an L3 switch) and also IGMP snooping, so you do have IGMP snooping enabled.  Try removing the "ip igmp querier" command.  Where is your L3 switch for this setup that is running IGMP?

Comment: @KarlBillington just quick input before i read more on the manual Ron linked to: It is a Layer 2 switch series. Do not have a layer 3 switch running IGMP. The layer 3 switch has IGMP disabled. This is the "core switch" with dedicated IP address (IGMP Querier: [this switch] 10.0.0.2 it says on show ip igmp) the multicast packages comes from port 1 in the core switch and goes out to port 2 even thought it is not subscribed to any multicast

Comment: Is the PC actually sending IGMP joins?  Can you see any in tcpdump?  Does "show ip igmp" show any groups being learned?  If the PC isn't sending any joins and the group is unknown to the switch it will likely flood the traffic

Comment: @RonMaupin If the guide you are looking at is 7.4 it is likely for the Aruba mobility switches which run a different code to the 2530, completely different OS and CLI.  The 2530 runs the version of ArubaOS that was previously Procurve, has much higher version numbers 14, 15, 16 etc

Comment: @KarlBillington, it is what the site returned for that switch model. I have no idea which version he is running, as it is not in the OP.

Comment: Hi both, the pc is not sending any joins there are no groups forming, te he switch is sending all I Multicast to all ports on the vlan which is what I am trying to stop as every active port has 50Mb of data constantly. I'll find the version tomorrow and see. Thank you so far:)

Comment: @RonMaupin No problem, just didn't want you to waste your time on the wrong manual.  It is confusing but as HPE bought Aruba most of the switching side is on the HPE website now, but branded Aruba

Comment: @Aninano Ah, OK, this may not work then.  IGMP snooping relies on reading the IGMP messages to work out which ports it should send the multicast on.  If it doesn't learn about a group (i.e. no IGMP messages), it has to flood the traffic as if the group isn't using IGMP, the traffic still needs to reach the receivers

Comment: Allright, seems like tomorrow is finding out how to enable snooping on this L2 switch :), will update here tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: @Aninano the snooping side is enabled, it is IGMP you need to enable - on the core switch.  If the host isn't sending joins already, it may not help enabling a querier, but you could try it

Comment: @all The Aruba 2530 switch is actually a HPE/Procurve one that's been rebranded with several Aruba features added.

Comment: Here are a screenshot from my switch config and version number. As you see IGMP is on and it has gotten a subscribe on one group (the MDSN group from the TV) but still i get all the multicast data on all LAN ports. See image here: http://link.jepb.no/ssq5

Comment: A L2-switch supposed to do IGMP snooping for a given VLAN/subnet needs to know the "mrouter port" (cf Kar Billington's edited answer). It snoops for IGMP group queries or PIM hello packets, and thus learns the mrouter port.

IGMP snooping will not work without an IGMP querier. Often, a router or L3-switch somewhere in that VLAN will act as IGMP querier, as soon as its IP interface into that VLAN gets PIM or IGMP enabled. If neither is feasible, a L2 switch may act as IGMP querier, _if_ it has an IP interface (`interface vlan NNN`) in the given VLAN/subnet, to send the IGMP queries from.

Comment: @Aninano Being a Cisco person, I would expect `show ip igmp groups` to show the output from a multicast _router_'s layer-3 perspective. Hence the output shown has no information about layer-2 switchports. Does the switch to which your PC is connected support something like `show ip igmp snooping groups`? That should show the perspective from layer-2 _switch_, which is - i believe - what we are after, in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the PC is not sending any IGMP joins you can't really benefit from IGMP snooping.

IGMP snooping relies on listening to (snooping) passing IGMP packets.  These packets contain information on which multicast groups the PC wants to join.  The switch is then able to make a decision on which ports to send multicast traffic for the group to and which ones to block.

Now consider a group where IGMP is not operating.  The source and receivers would need to be on the same VLAN.  If you enabled IGMP snooping in this case and there was no IGMP traffic to snoop, the switch will not have any ports in its IGMP snooping table for the group, so the traffic would get black holed.  To avoid this, if the switch doesn't receive any IGMP packets for the group it doesn't track the group and instead floods the traffic.

So in your case the traffic is flooded as the group is not learned as there are no IGMP packets.

You could try configuring IGMP on the L3 switch for VLAN 10, although if the PC is not sending joins now, it may not send them when it gets a query.

Note: Some vendors implement a feature for source only VLANs where the group can be learned by listening to the multicast source for cases where there are no receivers on the VLAN.  IGMP also adds ports where IGMP queriers can be heard to the table, so now the switch can efficiently forward traffic from the source to the router without flooding and without receiving any IGMP packets.

**Edit:**

Here is the section in RFC 4541 that talks about this issue:

> An unregistered packet is defined as an IPv4 multicast packet with a
>   destination address which does not match any of the groups announced
>   in earlier IGMP Membership Reports.
>
> If a switch receives an unregistered packet, it must forward that
>   packet on all ports to which an IGMP router is attached.  A switch may
>   default to forwarding unregistered packets on all ports. Switches that
>   do not forward unregistered packets to all ports must include a
>   configuration option to force the flooding of unregistered packets on
>   specified ports.

So if you try the advice above (configure "ip igmp" on VLAN 10 of the L3 core switch), your core will send IGMP queries and the switch can then learn the location of the IGMP router.  It may then revert to sending any traffic for unregistered groups to the core only.

Comment: But in this is have I don't want the pc to get the multicasts, that's why it's not sending any packages, but it still receives all 5 multicasts. I want a TV later on to receive though. But other units in the network (raspberrys, NASCAR e.t.c will never send a join message. Are they then doomed to be spammed by all multicasts forever? :)

Comment: It may work once the TV is on the network, if it sends IGMP join messages.  You could also look at moving the source to another VLAN where there are no other devices.  You would need to enable multicast routing and PIM on the L3 switch as well as IGMP on the VLAN where the TV sits

Comment: If you try configuring "ip igmp" on VLAN 10 of the core switch, the switch may alter its behaviour once it hears a query and start sending all unjoined multicast traffic to the core (excluding the local groups).  You would get all streams on the switch uplink, but wouldn't get any traffic arriving on the PC ports

Comment: I've made a discovery here, sending packages on 239.0.0.1 I cannot join but if i send on 239.1.0.1 the moment I join the group the packages are stopped from beeing broadcasted to all. I could not find anything specific on 239.0.0.X range. The Wikipedia page for IGMP says its routable. If we find out why we can add it to your answer and set it as correct answer. I'll google more! :)

Comment: Another problem to this problem, when i leave the group it start flooding again. Seeing RFC 4541 it says some switch does not flood ports. Might be that this is the wrong kinda switch?

Comment: That sounds expected.  If you leave a group, IGMP snooping will see the leave and if the client is the last receiver it will remove the group and revert to flooding.  It will only filter while it knows the group

Comment: That sounds expected after the protocol but normally every router has IGMP Flooding disabled, I tried a new router the HP 2520G which states in manual: [screengrab from manual](https://imgur.com/a/hlPJUHq) that it actually should not flood. It has an IP on that VLAN too.

Comment: The problem we had on the Aruba switch was actually because we used xxx.0.0.xx ip address. Are there some documentation on why thoose IP'adresses are not possible to join and are fully broadcasted without a join? Once we changed to e.g. 239.0.1.1 and upwards it worked perfectly. Maybe add that to the answer if we find documentation for it

Comment: It's down to the fact that L3 multicast addresses are mapped to L2 addresses automatically, but there are less bits available in the MAC than there are in the IP, so some bits don't getting copied.  Essentially there is no way to distinguish between those addresses and ones with 224.0.0.X IPs - and these are only designed to operate on-link, so no routing and no IGMP, they are flooded by default See https://www.fragmentationneeded.net/2010/10/mapping-multicast-groups-to-mac.html

Comment: [link](http://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/_notes_on_multicast_address_assignment.html) this page explaind it to me also. That was our problem actually on that switch, once we changed streams to multicast 239.0.1.1 it stopped flooding. Thanks for all :) Maybe add that to ur answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `show ip igmp` to check whether IGMP snooping is configured correctly and working as required.

We use just `vlan <vid> ip igmp`. I'm not sure what the `ip igmp querier` actually does, the manual doesn't provide much detail - I think it turns on the querier *capability* which is on by default anyway.

`vlan <vid> ip igmp querier help` displays

```
Description: Specify querier/non-querier capability for the VLAN. IGMP
             queries are not sent when the mode is disabled. When
             enabled, the device cannot become Querier for the subnet
             unless the VLAN has an IP Address (use the 'show ip' command
             to determine this).  Each subnet must have at least one IGMP
             Querier-capable device in order for IGMP to function
             properly.  The querier interval setting modifies the time (in
             seconds) between IGMP queries.
```

So, make sure there's an IP address configured on the VLAN or there's another switch/device used as querier.