# Multicast flooding network ProCurve Switch 2520G

Tags: switch, hp, igmp

**Switch**: ProCurve Switch 2520G-8-PoE

**Scenario**: Multicast is flooded onto the network

Having multicast flooded makes it so TV is stuttering and pixelating. I do on my ProCurve have IGMP and Querier enabled. The switch is the querier. My messages are still flooded onto every port on the same untagged vlan (5).

On the switch I see the groups are created by the TV as I switch channels still it sends out. Anyone aware if this switch is NOT able to stop multicast flooding by default? If so how do I enable it on this switch?

Running config:

```
vlan 5 
name "CC_CAST" 
untagged 2-5,8 
ip address 172.16.1.5 255.255.255.0 
tagged 1,7,9 
ip igmp 
exit
```

Show version gives:

```
ProCurve Switch 2520G-8-PoE(vlan-5)# show version
Image stamp:    /sw/code/build/walle(t4b_release)
                Jul 27 2009 01:04:24
                J.14.01
                474
Boot Image:     Primary
```

show ip igmp 5 config shows:

```
IGMP Service 

  VLAN ID : 5    
  VLAN NAME    : CC_CAST 
  IGMP Enabled [No] : Yes
  Forward with High Priority [No] : No 
  Querier Allowed [Yes] : Yes

  Port Type      | IP Mcast
  ---- --------- + --------
  1    1000T     | Auto    
  3    1000T     | Auto    
  4    1000T     | Auto    
  5    1000T     | Auto    
  7    1000T     | Auto    
  8    1000T     | Auto    
  9    1000T     | Auto
```

and show ip igmp 5

```
 Status and Counters - IP Multicast (IGMP) Status

 VLAN ID : 5
 VLAN Name : CC_CAST
 Querier Address : This switch is Querier

  Active Group Addresses Reports Queries Querier Access Port
  ---------------------- ------- ------- -------------------
  230.3.1.204            1       0                          
  239.255.3.22           374     0                          
  239.255.255.0          321     0                          
  239.255.255.10         321     0                          
  239.255.255.20         321     0                          
  239.255.255.30         321     0                          
  239.255.255.246        190     0                          
  239.255.255.250        967     0
```

show ip igmp group 230.3.1.204

```
 IGMP ports for group 230.3.1.204

  Port  Type      Access      Age Timer Leave Timer
  ----- --------- ----------- --------- -----------
  3     1000T     host        0         0
```

Comment: "_Having multicast flooded makes it so TV is stuttering and pixelating._" That is unlikely. Most switching is done in hardware at wire speed, and it is no more burdensome to the switch to send a frame to a single interface than it is to send it to all interfaces. There is something else causing your problem.

Comment: There are over 100Mbps data on each port so it's a problem. There are more data then what TV ethernet port is (10/100). The switch should be filtering out and only sending the multicast groups the TV joins?

Comment: But what happens on other switch interfaces has no bearing on what happens on the receiver interface. All the other interfaces could be completely busy, but if the receiver is only receiving the multicast, then it should work just fine. Switching is done in hardware, and almost all modern switches will switch at wirespeed. It is only if the receiver interface is receiving other traffic besides the multicast traffic that you may have interference, and then you use QoS to try to mitigate that.

Comment: Wasn’t this answered yesterday with a different switch model?

Comment: The problem is that on other switches we have possibility to disable multicast packages from being sent to all interfaces unless it joined the igmp group for that multicast stream. HP also states that this is default behavior for the switches, the eth0 interface on my pc is 100% all the time. Hope you understand what I mean.  (Link from hp)[http://h22208.www2.hpe.com/eginfolib/networking/docs/switches/RA/15-18/5998-8165_ra_2620_mrg/content/ch01s04.html] it says when one need a multicast it sends a join report. But I still get all without joining :P

Comment: Can you verify if igmp _snooping_ is actually working on the switch your PC and TV are connected to? What does igmp snooping feature's "show" output say is the mrouter port for vlan 5?

Comment: I wish I could, I am unable to find any commands mentioning snooping in the documentation. That's why I wonder if this switch really can filter multicast? According to specs it can and should do so as soon as igmp is enabled, which it is (show ip igmp vlan 5) and the multicast is in Port 2, TV in 3 and pc in 4.

Comment: As I pointed out in the other thread: 'show ip igmp groups' is probably a L3 thing and gives information as if that switch were an L3 device (read: single-attached multicast router) with an ip address in VLAN 5. But thats not what we're looking for. IGMP is a feature for multicast routers, so if the switches in question don't route, don't turn it on. Find a way to turn on igmp snooping for VLAN 5 on ALL involved switches carrying VLAN 5. Then, activate exactly one IGMP Querier in VLAN 5. If that won't help, you'll probably have to contact HPE support.

Comment: "show ip igmp group vlan 5" shows the groups e.g: the TV is a member of 239.255.255.250 and 239.0.1.1. 239.0.1.1 is the tv channel it is currently tuned to. The other one is simple service discovery. So groups works perfectly. Switch has vlan address 172.16.0.5 as seen above and igmp is enabled :-/

Comment: Turn igmp (feature for a routing or layer 3 device) off, turm on igmp snooping  (feature for a layer 2 device or switch). Your problem is very probably at layer 2, not at layer 3. Command outputs as shown so far all refer to layer 3 functions. Ouput from a layer 2 related command (is there really no 'show ip igmp snooping groups' available on that box?) would mention which groups are being forwarded out of which (layer 2) switch ports.

Comment: Oh well, according to documentation, they made a pretty good mumblefumble of L2 and L3 related IGMP config and show commands at HPE. :-/ What's the output of 'show ip igmp vlan 5 config'?

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi: I've updated the first post with the output of both config and not config. 230.3.1.204 is the current TV channel, if i change channel i also change the multicast ip there. So IGMP join and leave works perfectly.

Comment: A bit of research through documentation (like http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c02563903-4.pdf)  lets me suspect that HPE seemingly chose to deliver igmp, igmp querier and igmp snooping as a single automagic feature. Well, that is one way to try it. Activating "IGMP" on a layer2 switch is a misnomer to start with, not keeping L3 and L2 multicast features distinct by name is another...

Comment: (cont'd).  The doc linked above suggests (Page B-19) to use the `show ip igmp group <group.addr>` command to see some more detailed L2-related information about the given group address - including the switchports. Please let the querier election take place, start a TV stream and show us that command's output while the stream is running. I wonder what it has to say about the port which is _not_ meant to receive it.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi: Added to main post the output. The funny thing is that when i JOIN the group that channel stops broadcasting to "all" channels. So that actually works, but all the other channels are still broadcasted to all ports. I was hoping it would stop _all_ multicast packages at switch, then just send the one who has a group joined to the port. This is how our other HP switches (bigger core switches) work as I understood it

Comment: It is working as expected and as per the other post.  If no hosts join a group, it will get flooded.  It makes sense as if a group isn’t using IGMP the switch has no way of learning where the hosts live, so it must flood the traffic

Comment: I hear you clear and loud but there are a troubleshooting point on the manual where it states: question: multicast are flooded to all ports on vlan, answer: be sure that the vlan has ip address and multicast are enabled, which for me seems like it should not be doing this as per default. It also states that this switch has igmp capabilities to stop the flow of multicast, somehow it is not properly working. Who would want to use a switch which saturates the network. Normal behavior for most igmp enabled switch is to block multicast as I read online. So there must be a configuration error here?

Comment: You should read _[RFC 4541, Considerations for Internet Group Management Protocol (IGMP) and Multicast Listener Discovery (MLD) Snooping Switches](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc45410)_. While an Informational RFC, other RFC refer to it as a standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Aruba 2530 - IGMP Enabled, Querier on still no filtering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51719/aruba-2530-igmp-enabled-querier-on-still-no-filtering)

And RFC 4541

If no receivers join the group, then the switch can either flood the traffic to the IGMP querier or alternatively default to flooding the traffic.  In this case it is flooding the traffic.

It makes sense as some multicast streams, ones that are designed not to be routed, may not use IGMP.  This allows all hosts to receive the traffic.

You need to make sure that all groups are joined if you want to cut down on the flooding.

The 2520G is an older model, which is end of sale.  It may be missing some of the newer features that other Procurve/ArubaOS switches have.  Try upgrading to the latest software if you have any issues.

Comment: Quote: On HP switches that do support data-driven IGMP ("Smart" IGMP), when unregistered multicasts are received the switch automatically filters (drops) them. Thus, the sooner the IGMP leave is processed, the sooner this multicast traffic stops flowing. End quote See [link](goo.gl/eGZMsn). So basically what I'm asking is does this switch support data-driven IGMP. Since flooding the network with over 100Mbit saturates all the TV's and generate pixelation. Then i can "add" to that on my Aruba 2530, does it support data-driven IGMP. I have tried looking but cannot see it.

Comment: The software on the switch appears to be 6-7 years old, try upgrading to J.15.09.0028. https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9298A

Comment: You could also try configuring "igmp filter-unknown-mcast", wr mem, then reboot the switch

Comment: @KarlBillington J.14.01 is definitely ancient (2009), probably the first 2520 release. Seconding the update, likely to solve the problem.

Comment: @KarlBillington after installing upgrade "igmp filter-unknown-mcast" is added as a function and this works perfectly. So most switches with igmp support are ment to not flood network. Also TV is not pixelating anymore. Now I'm back to test on the Aruba one. It has filter-unknown-mcast enabled still it spams. But going back to that thread when i have questions. Thanks

Comment: great, make sure you save the config then reload after entering "igmp filter-unknown-mcast" as per the manual